# Good Admin Console for Tomcat 6 and above

Tags: java, tomcat

Any good Tomcat 6 admin module like Glassfish admin screens. For example i want to monitor open sessions or which jsp page gets how much hit ? Any admin module like that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is a community fork of Lambda Probe called [psi-probe](http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/) that is frequently updated.

Answer (score 1):

Though it hasn't been updated for a while, [Lambdaprobe](http://www.lambdaprobe.org/d/index.htm) seems promising and worth a try.

Comment: It is really cool but datasource controller is not working properly. Anyway I seems great admin console.